# How to deploy Django app from bazaar branch with juju?

Tags: juju, cloud, django

I'm attempting to deploy a Django app from bazaar branch with juju using the `python-django` charm. I've followed the quick start directions from the `README.md` file:

```
juju bootstrap
juju deploy --config mydjangosite.yaml python-django

juju deploy postgresql
juju add-relation python-django postgresql:db

juju deploy gunicorn
juju add-relation python-django gunicorn
juju expose python-django
```

My `mydjangosite.yaml` file looks like:

```
mydjangosite:
    vcs: bzr
    repos_url: lp:mydjangosite
```

It seems like the quick start directions must be missing something. This successfully deploys a running Django instance, but it's just the hello world app that displays:

> ### It worked!
>
> Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.

If I ssh into the Django instance, I don't see my `bzr` branch anywhere. `/srv/python-django/` just contains the default juju Django project files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using juju-core (the Go version of Juju). The config file
must be formatted differently as I explain in the documentation:

> Note:
>
> If your using juju-core you must remove the first line
>      of the file and the indentation for the rest of the file.

Otherwise, it won't give you an error but the configuration file
will be ignored.

So `mydjangosite.yaml` should really be in the form:

```
 vcs: bzr
 repos_url: lp:mydjangosite
```